# excel formula error - too few arguments

Tags: excel-formula

I'm getting an error with this statement that I have too few arguments:

```
=IFS(AND(D8="Hourly Field",C8<24),
   1,IFS(AND(D8="Hourly Field",C8>=24,C8<48),
   2,IFS(AND(D8="Hourly Field",C8>=48,C8<108),
   3,IF(AND(D8="Hourly Field",C8>=108),
   4))
```

When I change from of the parentheses to square brackets, I get an error that this is not a formula:

```
=IFS(AND(D8="Hourly Field",C8<24),
   1,IFS[AND(D8="Hourly Field",C8>=24,C8<48)],
   2,IFS[AND(D8="Hourly Field",C8>=48,C8<108)],
   3,IF(AND(D8="Hourly Field",C8>=108)),
   4)
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 6):

With IFS() you do not need to nest others:

```
=IFS(AND(D8="Hourly Field",C8<24),1,AND(D8="Hourly Field",C8>=24,C8<48),2,AND(D8="Hourly Field",C8>=48,C8<108),3,AND(D8="Hourly Field",C8>=108),4)
```

---

Edit

Your formula can be shortened to:

```
=IF(D8="Hourly Field",IFS(C8<24,1,C8<48,2,C8<108,3,C8>=108,4))
```